# I need HTML that will fail parsing by html.Parse()

Tags: html, go

I am writing a Go function to read an HTML response body and extract the page title.  Overall, the function works just great, but I want to test the code path where the response body isn't proper HTML at all.  My simplistic attempts to create some invalid HTML for unit tests have come to naught.

Apparently, and according to the [`html.Parse` documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Parse), this is because:

> the HTML5 parsing algorithm […] is very complicated. The resultant tree can contain implicitly created nodes that have no explicit `<tag>` listed in r's data, and nodes' parents can differ from the nesting implied by a naive processing of start and end `<tag>`s. Conversely, explicit `<tag>`s in r's data can be silently dropped, with no corresponding node in the resulting tree.

Here is some code demonstrating the sort of approach I've been taking:

https://play.golang.org/p/T5WjdtjNcqq

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    inputs := []string{ "",
        "~",
        "<",
        "<ht",
        "<html",
        "<html>",
        "<html><",
        "<html><titl",
        "<html><title",
        "<html><title>",
        "<html><title>The C Progr",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language<",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</ti",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</title",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</title>",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</title><",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</title></",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</title></ht",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</title></html",
        "<html><title>The C Programming Language</title></html>",
    }

    for _, in := range inputs {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", in)

        r := bytes.NewReader([]byte(in))
        _, err := html.Parse(r)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("COULD NOT PARSE HTML\n")
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Silly me, I would have expected many of these to yield an error since at face value they are invalid HTML, but the above code sails through all of the input strings without `panic`'ing -- that is, with no non-`nil` `err` from `html.Parse()`.

I suppose I am grateful for a lenient / tolerant HTML parser, but: Does anyone have an example of text that would yield an error when fed to Go's `html.Parse()`?

**EDIT 1**

Combining ideas from comments by Ferrybig and CreationTribe, I even tried a huge stream of random bytes:

```
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    in := make([]byte, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 2147483647; i++ {
        in = append(in, byte(rand.Intn(255)))
    }
    fmt.Printf("len(in) : %d\n", len(in))

    r := bytes.NewReader(in)
    _, err := html.Parse(r)
```

… and it still did not error.

Is there no input that will cause `html.Parse()` to error out?

Comment: You could things like too deeply nested tags, wrong html entities or an fully empty input

Comment: perhaps starting with closing tags then ending with the opening tag will yield an error? Or staggering tags that shouldn't be staggered? <span><div></span></div> or <table><td><div><tr></td></table></tr></td></div> ? Maybe even create a randomization program to throw random tags in mixed with random data, and give it a few runs through. You'll certainly end up with some error-yielding nonsense.

Comment: @Ferrybig : note that the 1st element in the input array is an empty string, and the 2nd one would, I think, but invalid outside of a tag; I'm willing to try deep nesting, but do you know how deep is "too deeply" nested?

Comment: @CreationTribe : I like your ideas for staggered tags, and added them to my Go Playground example, but they oddly passed muster, too

Comment: @Ferrybig : in an earlier test, I had also tried `&nope;`, but it also didn't cause an `err`

Comment: A full compliant html 5 parser (which the go parser claims to be) won't error for any input byte stream.

Comment: @Alohci Do you have a reference for that? So the Golang HTML5 parser just won't throw an error/exception?

Comment: You don't have to come up with invalid input. An io.Reader implementation that returns an error should do the trick.

Comment: To further what @Peter said, I had a look at the code (I recommend doing so whenever you have this kind of question; Go code tends to be easy to read) and without doing an extensive review, the only setting of the internal `Tokenizer.err` I spotted where to the error returned by the reader.

Comment: From what I can see in the code (https://github.com/golang/net/tree/ca1201d0/html), an error is returned if an `ErrorToken` is returned when parsing a token from the input (https://github.com/golang/net/blob/ca1201d0/html/parse.go#L2280). However, it is unclear to me how to get a `Token` of type `ErrorToken`.

Comment: A comment in the code (https://github.com/golang/net/blob/ca1201d0/html/token.go#L135) states that it seems to be possible : *For example, if the HTML text input was just "plain", then the first Next call would set z.err to io.EOF but return a TextToken, and all subsequent Next calls would return an ErrorToken*. I don't understand the "*was just "plain"*" part, but if someone have an idea, maybe we can find an input able to make `html.Parse()` return an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick read of https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/html/token.go, it seems that the only returned errors can be:

- io.EOF once r is fully read successfully;
- any other errors returned by the underlying io.Reader; or
- html.ErrBufferExceeded

It's not obvious to me after an initial read how trigger ErrBufferExceeded, but you could trigger an error from html.Parse by providing a dummy reader:

```
type ErrReader struct { Error error }

func (e *ErrReader) Read([]byte) (int, error) {
    return nil, e.Error
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/s78HpfMLAI8

Hope that helps

Comment: yes, this helps a lot; with a small change to the code where I'm actually doing this, I now inject the io.Reader, so that my production code can read the HTML and one of my unit tests can exercise the parse-error code path;  thanks!